# Move folder depending on foldername

Tags: linux, bash

So I have this idea of moving folders to different places depending on what the name of the source folder is.

I have came up with this little script, which does kind of work. It mismatches some names, and also it sometimes just straight up doesn't work.

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for result in $(ls -d /path/to/folders/*/);
do
Size=${#result}
StripFrom=$(expr index "$result" 'S\b[0-9]\b')
Strip=4
Stripped=$(($StripFrom-$Strip))
EndStrip=$(($Size-$Stripped))
EndStrip=-$EndStrip
Serie=${result:23:$EndStrip}
mv $result /path/to/TV/$Serie/
done
```

What I'm trying to do:

- Get a list of all folders in "/path/to/folders/"
- For each of them, search for the text S0, S1, S2 e.t.c.
- Get the name of the tv-show which is the part infront of "S[0-0]"
- Then move the folder to "/path/to/TV/Name-of-show"

I don't know if I'm going at this the wrong way all together.

23 is the number of characters in the path `/path/to/folders/`, by the way.

Comment: Can you give an example of start directory names, and what the resultant names/directories will be?

Comment: start name could be Gotham.S01E14.720p.x264-lozer
Result string would be "Gotham"

Comment: But the spec would have that result in `Gotham.`, including the period.

Comment: Oh, that's correct, sorry I was a bit unclear in my request, it should keep everything infront of S[0-9] except the last character

Comment: And they are all in that format? No spaces in any of the names?

Comment: No spaces in names, if there's a space in the name it would be like The.Simpsons.S24

Comment: And all the directories you are moving to already exist?

Comment: Yes, they do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the series name with a regular expression:

```
regex='/([^/]*).S[[:digit:]]{2}[^/]*/$'

for dir in /path/to/folders/*/; do
    if [[ $dir =~ $regex ]]; then
        mv "$dir" /path/to/TV/"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done
```

The expression looks for `S` followed by two digits between the last two `/` of the path and captures everything between the second last `/` and the `S`, minus the character before the `S`.

For an example content of `/path/to/folders/` of

```
folders
├── show1.S01E14.blahblah
├── show2.S11E01.text
└── unrelateddir
```

the commands issued are

```
mv /path/to/folders/show1.S01E14.blahblah/ /path/to/TV/show1
mv /path/to/folders/show2.S11E01.text/ /path/to/TV/show2
```

---

Remarks for your script:

- You don't have to loop over the output of `ls` as in `$(ls -d /path/to/folders/*/)` (see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) why that isn't a good idea in general), you can use the glob directly.
- Not entirely sure about this one, but `S\b[0-9]\b` would fail to match and `S` followed by two digits, as there is no word boundary between the digits.
- In arithmetic expansion, you don't need the `$` signs: `Stripped=$(($StripFrom-$Strip))` can be written `Stripped=$(( StripFrom - Strip ))`.

Comment: Oh, well that's a whole of a lot cleaner, I should really learn some more/proper regex. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to make things easier:

```
find /path/to/folders -name \*S[0-9]\* | while read $p
do
    result=$(basename "$p")
    SEASON=$(expr "$result" : '[[:print:]]\+\(S[[:digit:]]*\)')
    SHOW=$(expr "$result" : '\([[:print:]]\+\)S[[:digit:]]*') # with the trailing "."
    echo "show: $SHOW / season: $SEASON"
done
```